# How can I remove .php extension from only one URL in root directory without affecting sub-domains?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to hide .php extension from an URL (www.domain.com/home.php) using .htaccess.

The thing is when I use the generic examples I found it disables `php` for the entire server due to the "home.php" file being located there. Resulting in apps like Wordpress etc to not function correctly located in sub-directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^/]+)\.php(?:\s|\?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```